# Is "educated" an egotistical word in this scenario?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Here is the scenario:

> Somebody asked a question about Catholicism. An Atheist responded with the correct answer. I was impressed and asked if this person was Catholic. This person said, "No, I'm just educated".

In this context, would the word "educated" mean that the person has an inflated opinion about himself or herself?

Comment: No. It simply means that one need not be Catholic to know about some things Catholic.

Comment: Assuming the person asking the question was asking because he/she wanted to know (e.g.. it is not in a quiz) there is an implication that any educated person would know this. By implication, the person who asked the question is not educated. So to me it would come across as an egotistical put-down. An alternative would be "it's just something I picked up", or "I once read a book" or "my auntie is".

Comment: Agree with @davidlol . He was being a smart ass.

Comment: A news broadcast recently reported that Pope Francis is considering ordaining married men to the priesthood. This broadcast said he was considering changing Catholic doctrine. But Catholicism has a clear distinction between _doctrines_ (which are considered immutable and infallible) and _disciplines_ (which are quite mutable and are fallible), and celibacy of priests has always been clearly labeled a discipline rather than a doctrine. So the broadcast was in error. I wonder how many Catholics have a clear understanding of this? I've seen journalists get really confused about such simple...

Comment: ....technical points about Catholicism.

Comment: @Michael Hardy They're not simple technical points. Some would consider it a vital matter of correct doctrine that there is no prelacy-style priesthood in the Church, and that leaders will often be married. See [GotQuestions.org?](https://www.gotquestions.org/celibacy-priests.html), for instance, for the relevant Bible extracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of principle.

On one hand, the atheist may consider himself to know Catholicism without being Catholic, due to having a superior level of education.

On the other hand, in this sense, imagine different synonyms for educated. Informed, knowledgeable, even intelligent. Informed, is in a similar situation; the atheist may try to assert superiority, or just may be aware of Catholic traditions. Knowledgeable is less assertive, by implying a broad level of knowledge. Using intelligent instead of educated definitely implies superiority, however. In that regard, he would be claiming that the Catholic is not intelligent, because they are Catholic. It gives a prejudicial overtone.

"Well educated" would be a far better term to use instead, as, much like knowledgeable, it would imply intellect in a wide variety of areas, not just claiming higher levels of intelligence over another person.